# Proof of induction principle

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Theorem 1.1.3 (induction principle) of Dirk Van Dalen "Logic and Structure" states:

Let $A$ be a property, then $A(\phi)$ holds for all $\phi \in PROP$ if:

- $A(p_i)$, for all i;
- $A(\phi),A(\psi) \Rightarrow A(\phi \square \psi)$
- $A(\phi) \Rightarrow A(\neg \phi)$

I don't understand the little proof he gives. He writes let $X=\{\phi \in PROP | A(\phi) \}$, then X satisfies the conditions of the recursive definition of $PROP$. So $PROP \subseteq X$,i.e. for all $\phi \in PROP$ $A(\phi)$ holds.

Comment: There must a definition before that theorem that says that $PROP$ is the smallest set that satisfies the given properties. Since $X$ satisfies the given properties, then certainly it is larger than the smallest set which satisfies these properties. Thus $PROP\subseteq X$.

Comment: No problem. If no one posts an answer in a 'reasonable' amount of time, it would be good if you answered the question yourself so it doesn't come up as unanswered.

Comment: Sure I'll do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof comes from the fact that *PROP* is the smallest set of well-formed formulae. The proof van Dalen gives is correct, but too brief. As he defines $X=\{\phi \in PROP | A(\phi) \}$, then by the definition of *PROP*, which is the smallest set of well-formed formulae, it follows that $PROP \subseteq X$, otherwise it would be smaller than *PROP* itself.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of avoiding confusion, I feel it should be pointed out precisely in what sense *PROP* is the "smallest" set of well-formed formulae. For example, $\{10,11\}$ is certainly the smallest set of consecutive integers that add up to $21$, but that does not mean that it is a subset of $\{6,7,8\}$.

However, when it comes to being a set of all propositional formula, all the conditions are of the form "you must contain these things" and "if you contain these things you must also contain these things". Because of this very particular form (there are mathematically more precise ways to formulate it), it is the case that there *does* exist a set, namely *PROP*, such that if you satisfy the conditions, you must contain *PROP* as a subset.